# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to read my JSON result.

**Here is my RootObject**

```
public class RootObject
{
public int id { get; set; }
public bool is_default { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int quantity { get; set; }
public string stock { get; set; }
public string unit_cost { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my JSON result**

```
[{"id": 3636, "is_default": true, "name": "Unit", "quantity": 1, "stock": "100000.00", "unit_cost": "0"}, {"id": 4592, "is_default": false, "name": "Bundle", "quantity": 5, "stock": "100000.00", "unit_cost": "0"}]
```

Here is my code to read the result

```
     public static RootObject GetItems(string user, string key, Int32 tid, Int32 pid)
    {
        // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
        var url = string.Format(uniqueItemUrl, user, key, tid, pid);

        // Syncronious Consumption
        var syncClient = new WebClient();

        var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

    }
```

But I am having a problem with this error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'avaris_cash_salepoint.BL.UniqueItemDataRootObject' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or
>   a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection,
>   IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.

at this line:
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

Any help to fix this error ?

Comment: What is the content of  `var content` before it gets passed in to `DeserializeObject`?

Comment: content contains the json' result , @Dayan

Comment: Does it look exactly as your JSON example above?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that your JSON is a list of objects when it comes in and it doesnt directly relate to your root class.

`var content` would  look something like this (i assume):

```
[
  {
    "id": 3636,
    "is_default": true,
    "name": "Unit",
    "quantity": 1,
    "stock": "100000.00",
    "unit_cost": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": 4592,
    "is_default": false,
    "name": "Bundle",
    "quantity": 5,
    "stock": "100000.00",
    "unit_cost": "0"
  }
]
```

Note: make use of http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to format your JSON.

So if you try the following it should work:

```
  public static List<RootObject> GetItems(string user, string key, Int32 tid, Int32 pid)
    {
        // Customize URL according to geo location parameters
        var url = string.Format(uniqueItemUrl, user, key, tid, pid);

        // Syncronious Consumption
        var syncClient = new WebClient();

        var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(content);

    }
```

You will need to then iterate if you don't wish to return a list of `RootObject`.

---

I went ahead and tested this in a Console app, worked fine.

[image]

Comment: i have tried and i have the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to RootObject.

Comment: And `content` has the JSON i posted above?

Comment: yes the content has the json you posted above. but i think something must be done on the Rootobject class

Comment: I just tested your code in a Console App using Newtonsoft latest, and it worked fine. Look at my updated post.

Comment: I think you are still trying to return the list of RootObjects when your method definition is still set to a single `RootObject`. Hence, `public static RootObject GetItems` instead of `public static List<RootObject> GetItems`. Make sure your modify your method if you wish to do this, or just iterate and pick just 1 object from your collection and return that one object. Hope this helps clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this to solve your problem:

```
private async void btn_Go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.school-link.net/webservice/get_student/?id=" + txtVCode.Text);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await webClient.GetAsync(uri);
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var _Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Student>>(jsonString);
    foreach (Student Student in _Data)
    {
        tb1.Text = Student.student_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. The JSON that was returned was a list and this code iterated through the list to extract the items. Perfect!

Answer (score 4):

That's because the json you're getting is an array of your `RootObject` class, rather than a single instance, change your `DeserialiseObject<RootObject>` to be something like `DeserialiseObject<RootObject[]>` (un-tested).

You'll then have to either change your method to return a collection of `RootObject` or do some further processing on the deserialised object to return a single instance.

If you look at a formatted version of the response you provided:

```
[
   {
      "id":3636,
      "is_default":true,
      "name":"Unit",
      "quantity":1,
      "stock":"100000.00",
      "unit_cost":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":4592,
      "is_default":false,
      "name":"Bundle",
      "quantity":5,
      "stock":"100000.00",
      "unit_cost":"0"
   }
]
```

You can see two instances in there.

Comment: the instance can be more than one, with other parameters something i have one instance , or 3 04 four instance. @Psytronic

Answer (score 1):

You have an array, convert it to an object, something like:

> data: [{"id": 3636, "is_default": true, "name": "Unit", "quantity": 1, "stock": "100000.00", "unit_cost": "0"}, {"id": 4592, "is_default": false, "name": "Bundle", "quantity": 5, "stock": "100000.00", "unit_cost": "0"}]

Answer (score 0):

This could be You

Before trying to consume your json object with another object just check that the api is returning raw json via the browser api/rootobject, for my case i found out that the underlying data provider mssqlserver was not running and throw an unhanded exception !

as simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

---

> To read more than one json tip (array, attribute) I did the following.

---

```
var jVariable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourCommentaryClass>(jsonVariableContent);
```

> change to

```
var jVariable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<YourCommentaryClass>>(jsonVariableContent);
```

> Because you cannot see all the bits in the method used in the foreach
>   loop. 
>   Example foreach loop

```
foreach (jsonDonanimSimple Variable in jVariable)
                {    
                    debugOutput(jVariable.Id.ToString());
                    debugOutput(jVariable.Header.ToString());
                    debugOutput(jVariable.Content.ToString());
                }
```

> I also received an error in this loop and changed it as follows.

```
foreach (jsonDonanimSimple Variable in jVariable)
                    {    
                        debugOutput(Variable.Id.ToString());
                        debugOutput(Variable.Header.ToString());
                        debugOutput(Variable.Content.ToString());
                    }
```