# Asp.Net Wep Api 2 Error When Posting Json Object

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing 3 simple RESTFul services by using ASP.NET Web API 2 and EF6

The name of first service is ImageGallery, which returns ImageGallery json object from Database

I have two entities like these:

ImageGalley.cs:

```
public class ImageGallery
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

And Also, Image.cs:

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ImageGalleryID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageGallery ImageGallery { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller's Get method:

```
    public IList<ImageGallery> GetImageGalleries()
    {
        var imgGalls = db.ImageGalleries.ToList();
        return imgGalls;
    }
```

For Post:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ImageGallery))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostImageGallery(ImageGallery imageGallery)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.ImageGalleries.Add(imageGallery);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = imageGallery.ID }, imageGallery);
    }
```

I have put this line of code in my Global.asax to avoid self referencing loop:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

I'm using POSTMAN to get and post Json Objects. But when i'm trying the Post, i encounter that error.

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "imageGallery": [
      "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MobileApis.Models.ImageGallery' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my GET Response:

```
    [
  {
    "Images": [
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "ImageGalleryID": 1,
        "Caption": "Image 1",
        "Url": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
      },
      {
        "ID": 4,
        "ImageGalleryID": 1,
        "Caption": "Image 2",
        "Url": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
      },
      {
        "ID": 5,
        "ImageGalleryID": 1,
        "Caption": "Image 3",
        "Url": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
      },
      {
        "ID": 6,
        "ImageGalleryID": 1,
        "Caption": "Image 4",
        "Url": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
      }
    ],
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Image Gallery 1"
  }
]
```

I will be so happy, if you help me.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21885758/795683