# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the following JSON format delivered by a third party:

```
{
"data": {
    "objects": {
        "0ea73fa9333a7cbeb2d8c69a14b9970f": {
            "Id": "0ea73fa9333a7cbeb2d8c69a14b9970f",
            "Name": "test"
        },
        "38b1390ff6bc8a9837105d181000bcc8": {
            "Id": "38b1390ff6bc8a9837105d181000bcc8",
            "Name": "test"
        }
    }
}}
```

which i'm deserializing using this model:

```
public class ObjectTypes
{
    public ObjectTypeList data { get; set; }

    public class ObjectTypeList
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Object> objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works fine, however sometimes the JSON is empty like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "objects": []
}
}
```

Which results in this exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Models.ObjectTypes+Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path 'data.objects', line 1, position 20.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: @JeroenMink,  your `objects` is not an array `[]` its object `{}` so here `Dictionary<string, Object>` doesn't work here

Comment: @jeroen.mink do you have a sample json string that you cannot deserialize, i.e. throws an exception?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not naming a class `Object`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885243/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3

Comment: @RuiJarimba the last json (where the 'objects' property is empty is the one i can't deserialize

Comment: oops sorry @JeroenMink, I was distracted.

Comment: @JeroenMink if you look carefully you'll see that json structure is not the same. In your first json string `objects` is an object, in your second json string `objects` is an array, that's why you can't deserialize it.

Comment: @JeroenMink There is a bug in the code that produced the second snippet. If the `objects` element is empty, the JSON string should be `"objects":{}`. You *can't* deserialize an array as if it were a dictionary.

Comment: @JeroenMink, you second json `"objects": []` is always empty or may be it contains data?

Answer (score 0):

You shoul deserialize on the type **ObjectTypes**

```
        public partial class ObjectTypes
        {
            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public Data Data { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Data
        {
            [JsonProperty("objects")]
            public Dictionary<string, Object> Objects { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Object
        {
            [JsonProperty("Id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: That's what i'm doing. The exception originates on the

    public Dictionary<string, Object> Objects { get; set; }
        }

Comment: I see in your response that objects is an array

Comment: it should be
{
"data": {
    "objects": {}
}
}
not
{
"data": {
    "objects": []
}
}

@JeroenMink

Comment: @MuhamadEissa as the OP already mentioned, json strings are returned by a 3rd party. This means the OP cannot change the second json string from an array to an object

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment, json structure doesn't match in both strings. `objects` can be either an **object** (Dictionary) or an **array**.

I have created a small parser class that will parse the json and check if `objects` is an **object** (Dictionary) or an **array**. In the first case it will return an empty `ObjectTypes` object but in the second case it will deserialize the json string into an `ObjectTypes` object.

```
public class ObjectTypesParser
{
    public ObjectTypes Parse(string json)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
        var objectsToken = token.First.First.First.FirstOrDefault();

        if (objectsToken is JArray)
        {
            /*
             Special case - json with an empty array:

            {
                ""data"": {
                    ""objects"": []
                }
            }

            */
            return new ObjectTypes();
        }

        // json containing a dictionary:
        ObjectTypes data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectTypes>(json);

        return data;
    }
}
```

C# classes:

```
public class ObjectTypes
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public ObjectTypeList Data { get; set; }

    public ObjectTypes()
    {
        Data = new ObjectTypeList();
    }
}

public class ObjectTypeList
{
    [JsonProperty("objects")]
    public Dictionary<string, ObjectData> Objects { get; set; }

    public ObjectTypeList()
    {
        Objects = new Dictionary<string, ObjectData>();
    }
}

public class ObjectData
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using the code:

```
string json1 = @"{
""data"": {
    ""objects"": {
        ""0ea73fa9333a7cbeb2d8c69a14b9970f"": {
            ""Id"": ""0ea73fa9333a7cbeb2d8c69a14b9970f"",
            ""Name"": ""test""
        },
        ""38b1390ff6bc8a9837105d181000bcc8"": {
            ""Id"": ""38b1390ff6bc8a9837105d181000bcc8"",
            ""Name"": ""test""
        }
    }
}}";

string json2 = @"{
""data"": {
    ""objects"": []
}
}";


var parser = new ObjectTypesParser();
ObjectTypes data1 = parser.Parse(json1);
ObjectTypes data2 = parser.Parse(json2);
```