# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: json, go, deserialization, marshalling, unmarshalling

**Question:** What am I missing? Any guidance would be appreciated.

**Scenario**: I am attempting to collect form data and use an API to validate an address.

**Problem**: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object.

**Similar Posts:**

- [Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885243/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3)
- [Getting "because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly" error when deserializing a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427579/getting-because-the-type-requires-a-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-to-deserialize-co)

---

**Error:**

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShipEngine.Api.Contracts.Shared.Addresses.Address]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

---

**Code:**

```
package main
 
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Address struct {
    Address1    string `json:"address_line1"`
    Address2    string `json:"address_line2"`
    City        string `json:"city_locality"`
    State       string `json:"state_province"`
    Postal      string `json:"postal_code"`
    Country     string `json:"country_code"`
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.Error(w, "404 not found.", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
 
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":     
         http.ServeFile(w, r, "form.html")
    case "POST":
        // Call ParseForm() to parse the raw query and update r.PostForm and r.Form.
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Post from website! r.PostFrom = %v\n", r.PostForm)
        
        address1 := r.FormValue("address1")
        address2 := r.FormValue("address2")
        city := r.FormValue("city")
        state := r.FormValue("state")
        postal := r.FormValue("postal")
        country := r.FormValue("country")
        
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Address1 = %s\n", address1)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Address2 = %s\n", address2)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "City = %s\n", city)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "State = %s\n", state)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Postal = %s\n", postal)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Country = %s\n", country)
    

        // u1 := User{1, "John Doe", "gardener"}
        address := Address{
            Address1:   address1,
            Address2:   address2,
            City:   city,
            State:  state,
            Postal: postal,
            Country:    country,
        }

        json_data, err := json.Marshal(address)

        if err != nil {

            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(string(json_data))
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "JSON = %s\n", string(json_data))
        
        url := "https://api.shipengine.com/v1/addresses/validate"
        method := "POST"

        payload := strings.NewReader(string(json_data))

        client := &http.Client {}
        
        req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        req.Header.Add("Host", "api.shipengine.com")
        req.Header.Add("API-Key", "INSERT_SECRET_KEY")
        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

        res, err := client.Do(req)
        defer res.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

        fmt.Println(string(body))
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only GET and POST methods are supported.")
    }
}
 
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
 
    fmt.Printf("Starting server for testing HTTP POST...\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please print out the raw data being returned from the URL endpoint so we can determine where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ship Engine address validation API](https://www.shipengine.com/docs/addresses/validation/) takes an array of addresses to validate.  Use this code to generate a JSON array in the request:

```
    json_data, err := json.Marshal([]*Address{&address})
```

Not that this is related to the problem, but you can eliminate unnecessary memory allocations using this code to create the request body:

```
payload := bytes.NewReader(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending a single object instead of an array.
Take a look in the expected payload here: https://www.shipengine.com/docs/addresses/validation/